# Can the 3 nonlinear forward kinematics equations for higher degree of freedom (>3) manipulators always be converted into a single polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, kinematics

For the generic 3R robot manipulator (3 serial links connected by revolute joints), the equations describing the position of the end-effector (hand) in terms of the joint angles which are normally written as a system of 3 nonlinear equations (one for x, y, and z in the workspace) can be condensed into a single quartic in terms of one of the joint angles. For this case, one can for example create this polynomial in terms of $\tan(\theta_3/2)$. In [Kohli & Spanos, Workspace Analysis of Mechanical Manipulators Using Polynomial Discriminants](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/mechanicaldesign/article-abstract/107/2/209/433336/Workspace-Analysis-of-Mechanical-Manipulators?redirectedFrom=fulltext), they write:

> The determination of the joint variables for a specified
> position of the hand (last link) is conducted by obtaining a set
> of equations relating the joint variables and constant
> kinematic parameters of the manipulator linkage to the hand
> position variables. In general, this set of equations is reduced
> to one equation of polynomial form in only one joint
> variable.

seemingly claiming that this can be done for higher degree of freedom (DOF) serial manipulators as well. Is this always the case, i.e. can you convert the 3 nonlinear equations describing forward kinematics into a single polynomial in one variable? And if so, is there a generic method for doing so? For a 6 DOF robot, this polynomial would be up to 16-th order.

The closest to a derivation for the 3 DOF case I found is in [Using Computer Algebra Tools to Classify Serial Manipulators](ftp://ftp.risc.uni-linz.ac.at/pub/private/ADG02/corvez-rouillier.ps), but I can't figure out how they constructed the quartic.